# eclipse .js syntax highlighting for .jsp files

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp

I want to have JS syntax highlighting on my .jsp files. Syntax highlighting for .js files work fine, but as soon, as I rename the file to .jsp, the syntax highlighting switches to the default .jsp highlighting(which I don't need at all). I tried to fuzz around with the settings, but I am not able to remove the default JSP Editor, as it appears to be locked and not changeable as the "Remove" Button for the associated editors is not clickable(?). I think I would just need to remove the JSP Editor entry here, as the TextEditor/GenericTextEditor would bring the JS syntax highlights with it(?).
Here some screens of my settings:
the setting for .js files, which are working perfectly fine for js highlighting:
[image: settings for .js files]
and the settings for .jsp files, which are not working properly:
[image: settings for .jsp files]
last screen shows the highlighting as is on the .jsp files(which are obviously not working):
[image: code highlighting example]

any hints are highly appreciated ;)

**edit:**
tried the solution from comments. although it does not fix the syntax highlighting, it does something. eclipse now tries to validate the code which goes wrong. here a screen of the added entry and the result in the editor:
[image]
[image]

**edit:** after updating my eclipse the issue remains. version of wild web developer is now 0.10.12.202202041634:
[image]
eclipse itself is now on version 2022-03 (4.23.0):
[image]

Comment: Does in the content type _Text > Wild Web Developer supported web dev file > JavaScript_ adding the file association `*.jsp` help?

Comment: although it seems to make a difference(see edit to op) it unfortunately does not activate the syntax highlighting. thx for the hint though.

Comment: Your example (which I got via OCR from your screenshot) works for me in the current Eclipse. Your screenshot shows a pretty outdated Eclipse and maybe Wild Web Developer which does the syntax highlighting here is outdated too.

Comment: thanks again for the hint. I updated eclipse, but the issue still remains. editor still showing only .jsp syntax highlights. details in edit of op and sorry for make you using ocr to copy, but just text wouldn't have shown the highlighting ;)

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? `.jsp` is not an extension you typically see for JavaScript files, and it is the default for Java/Jakarta Server Pages.

Comment: my problem is as described, that i can not get it to work to have js syntax highlighting on .jsp files. I don't know how else I would express that. I don't think the purpose of my project is related to my stated problem here.

Comment: Are you trying to treat `.jsp` files as JavaScript, as generators of JavaScript, or get the syntax coloring in script areas of a JSP that generates HTML?

Comment: I want to  use the .jsp files to generate js content on request(depending on parameters of the request and a few more inputs). this generated js content is linked in (also via jsp generated) html with a simple '<script src="myGeneratedScript.jsp"></script>'. the page header should take care of the correct mimetype.